# Adding Polygon to shapefile of particular area from Excel?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, editing, excel

I have Excel data in which polygon number is given, in correspondence to that there is particular Area given. I have 5000 to these entries.
Now in the shape file, we have to edit every polygon and add area to it by cuting the polygon in two, one of which can be added by dividing area from one of the length from polygon and drawing new one (Shown in green marking)and have to give new attributes to it from ecxel by copy pasting(Shown in red circle) 
As it is a repetitive process. I was exploring if there is a way i can use this excel data with python code and all the attributes get edit in shape file at once.

Basically I want to automate this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am using ArcGIS, Fields are same.

Comment: Actually, We have to edit that polygon cut it into two , one of the area given in excel.

Comment: sure , Thanks a lot for your support..

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Your exact workflow is not clear, but in general as long as each feature has an ID or field value that uniquely matches one row in the spreadsheet, Python can load the spreadsheet into a dictionary and a cursor can transfer the attribute data to the feature.  The general concepts for using dictionaries and cursors are shown in my Turbo Charging Data Manipulation with Python Cursors and Dictionaries blog.  https://community.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries